# OMAP l138 Emif interface to FPGA

Tags: fpga, omap

I have to design an interface between [OMAP L138](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/sprs586d/sprs586d.pdf) and an FPGA through the emif. I need to read data from the FPGA and send it to the OMAP for processing and write the processed data back onto the FPGA.

Can someone please tell me how to access the registers in the omap that have to be configured in order to get the emif to work?

Can I directly access the registers of the OMAP by giving the address to the emif and writing to it using the data bus?

Comment: I have gone through the datasheet. I am still confused so can you please tell me.

Comment: Often an effective way to tackle utilizing a peripheral interface on an unfamiliar chip is to try to find an manufacturer's reference example which uses the peripheral in a way somewhat similar to what you want.  Build and test that, then start adapting it towards your need.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have to call a ROM function in the Bootloader to configure these registers.  Appendix D in the Texas Instruments [Using the OMAP-L132/L138 Bootloader](http://www.ti.com/lit/an/sprab41e/sprab41e.pdf) application note has the ROM function that writes the EMIF registers.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the EMIF to directly access an area of the FPGA.  You'll have to write code that makes the FPGA emulate a memory type that the EMIF understands.  Do some sums on your liekly bandwidth and latency requirements first as that will guide you as to which memory-type to emulate.

Then it's "just" a case of sitting down with the datasheet and writing HDL code for the FPGA to emulate the memory type, simulating, synthesising and testing.

Comment: This is a useful answer to the topic in general, but doesn't seem to answer the actual question.  At least in my reading, the actual question is how to configure the EMIF interface in the OMAP, not how to create the FPGA side.

Comment: but that depends on how the FPGA is set up.... It's all a bit circular....

Comment: Thanks a lot. But I wanted to know how can I set the control registers in the OMAP that the EMIF requires, like CEnCFG, AWCC and such.I would be very grateful if anyone could give me an example.